# Wait for response of a function in Extjs

Tags: extjs

I have a code in which i'm calling a function and that function having Ajax request so it's taking a bit time to execute .. but at same time my next line code executed.. i want to stop next line code execution until my first line code is executing ...

here is my code -

```
    RWM.util.AjaxRequest.getPost(val); 

    alert('d');
```

and inside AjaxRequestclass i have getPost function -

```
 getPost: function(postno) {

  Ext.Ajax.request(

       {

         url: 'data/php/postnumber.php?mode=getById'

           ,method: 'GET'

           ,params: {
                postno: postno
            }

            ,success: function(response) {
               alert('s');

  }

  });
}
```

So here i want to execute alert('s') then alert('d')

Any Idea ?

Comment: I found my self - 

RWM.util.AjaxRequest.getPost(val);
setTimeout(function(){alert('d');}, 500);

Comment: That's not the answer... What if your Ajax request takes longer then 0.5 sec?

Comment: please read up on "callbacks"

Answer (score 0):

Put `alert('d');` in a callback block as Neil McGuigan recommends:

```
RWM.util.AjaxRequest.getPost(val, function() { alert('d'); }); 

getPost: function(postno, callback) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'data/php/postnumber.php?mode=getById'
        ,method: 'GET'
        ,params: {
            postno: postno
         }
        ,success: function(response) {
            alert('s');
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

Have a look at [sample on Ext Forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?227367-Ext.Ajax.Request-inside-function&highlight=Ext.Ajax.request).